# How do I use PHP code in a block?

Tags: 8, blocks

I am new to Drupal 8. I am building a website with Drupal 8, and it has many blocks contain images. They have an absolute path for the src attribute right now. I would like to make them dynamic base on the base URL, but there is no text format support PHP code anymore for security reason. Is there a safe way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could and should do your PHP logic with [template_preprocess_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x). As creating a programmatic block just so you can use PHP is more work than necessary, overkill, for this use case.

Also, without any more specific info regarding `make them dynamic based on base URL`, this is as far as I can go.

Comment: Cheers man, thank you for providing that solution.